# Skill output mapping to Edm.DateTimeOffset field

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is there a way in Azure Cognitive search to map output of skill to DateTimeOffset field?
Getting an error:

Skill returns:

> {
> "values": [
> {
> "recordId": "0",
> "data": {
> "date": "2020-09-25T04:00:00.0000000Z"
> },
> "errors": null,
> "warnings": null
> }
> ]
> }

Indexer maps the skill output

> "outputFieldMappings" :
> [
> {
> "sourceFieldName": "/document/message_date",
> "targetFieldName": "message_date"
> }
> ]

where message_date defined as

> {
> "name": "message_date",
> "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset",
> "sortable": true,
> "searchable": false,
> "filterable": true,
> "facetable": false
> },

Getting indexer error:
The data field 'message_date' in the document with key 'NA_0138373324' has an invalid value of type 'Edm.String' (JSON String maps to Edm.String). The expected type was 'Edm.DateTimeOffset'

How to force indexer to convert it to date ? there is no mapping function like that

Answer (score -1):

> Date and time values represented in the OData V4 format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff[+&#124;-]HH:mm`. Precision of `DateTimeOffset` fields is limited to milliseconds. **If you upload `DateTimeOffset` values with sub-millisecond precision, the value returned will be rounded up to milliseconds** (for example, 2015-04-15T10:30:09.7552052Z will be returned as 2015-04-15T10:30:09.7550000Z). When you upload `DateTimeOffset` values with time zone information to your index, Azure Cognitive Search normalizes these values to UTC. For example, 2017-01-13T14:03:00-08:00 will be stored as 2017-01-13T22:03:00Z. If you need to store time zone information, you will need to add an extra field to your index.

You can changed your datetime format to:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ
```

Example:`"date": "2020-09-25T04:00:00Z"`